# Using multiple separator styles in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I want to consistently use two types of unit separators throughout my document: the default style, with small spaces and integral powers, and another that uses multiplication dots and/or a division slash with parentheses if necessary, all with positive exponents.  I want the slash and parentheses to size themselves based on the text in the denominator, and I want a small negative space around all separators and after exponents to keep the spacing relatively even and compact.

Here’s an example of what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
The unit of $\varepsilon_0$,
$\left.\mathrm{ F }\middle/\mathrm{ m }\right.$, 
can also be expressed as 
$\left.\mathrm{ C }^2\!\middle/\!\left( \mathrm{ \mathrm{ N }\!\cdot\!\mathrm{ m^2 } }\right.\! \right)$ 
or 
\si{kg^{-1}.m^{-3}.s^{4}.A^{2}}; 
its exact value equals 
$\left. 625 \, 000 \middle/ \left( 22 \, 468 \, 878 \, 468 \, 878 \, 468 \, 420 \, 441 \, \pi \right) \right.$. \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

The way I was thinking of doing this would be to create a `\newcommand` that would work as a shortcut for `\si[inter-unit-product={}\!\cdot{}\!]`.  However, I do not know how to edit the default “per” mode, because I need a `\left.` and `\right.` on each side of the unit, and I also want a `\!` after exponents.

How can I achieve these unit settings? Also, how could I have those commands for the forward slash and parentheses to apply when I use `siunitx` to format both the number and the unit?